# How to persist data in Core Data through delete and reinstall of the App

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have an iOS app that uses Core Data. I would like to make sure that the data does not get lost if the user deletes and re-installs the app. I was wondering if using iCloud with Core Data is the solution to what I wish to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Using iCloud should preserve the data and reload it upon fresh installation.